# adding a code snippet to a design in figma

Tags: figma

I'm creating a design using Figma (not FigJam) and I want to add a code snippet in C#. However, all the plugins I've seen don't support this language. How can I add a code snippet in C# to my Figma design so it looks professional and not a screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

I can advise you on two plugins but I didn't use them personally.

https://platform.uno/unofigma/#. - Design to C# and XAML Code

https://www.figma.com/community/plugin/1029415284789228817/Figma2xaml. - Let's make Figma friendly for C# developers. This plugin can help you convert vector shapes to xaml (eXtensible Application Markup Language).